# Hyperlink Underline using Border-Bottom Showing Up Under Site Logo Image

Tags: css, genesis-theme-framework, logo

I was underlining the hyperlinks on my Wordpress Genesis Theme using Border-Bottom in the CSS.

Basically, I did the CSS code below, which worked for all of my in-text links:

```
a {
    color: #03bf00;
        font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #03bf00;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
    color: #F12E2E;
        font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #F12E2E;
}
```

Even though the underline did appear some places I didn't want it to, like in menu areas, I was able to remove that by using border-bottom: none;

However, a border line is now showing up under my site logo image in the header.

I would like to remove that line, but everything I've tried is not working.

Basically, when I inspect the logo element, it seems to indicate that I should adjust this piece of code.

```
.site-header .custom-logo-link .custom-logo
```

So I went through all of the code in the title area and added border-bottom: none; but it didn't remove the line underneath the logo.

```
.title-area {
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.wp-custom-logo .title-area {
    height: 80px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 0;
    width: auto;
}

.site-title {
    display: none;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.site-title a,
.site-title a:hover,
.site-title a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.wp-custom-logo .site-title > a {
    float: left;
    min-height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
}

.wp-custom-logo .site-title {
    border-width: 0;
    clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
    height: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute !important;
    width: 1px;
    word-wrap: normal !important;
}

.site-description {
    display: none;
    border-width: 0;
    clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute !important;
    width: 0px;
    word-wrap: normal !important;
}

.site-header .custom-logo-link .custom-logo {
    height: 80px;
    width: auto;
}
```

I tried each of these class styles, but it didn't work.

I even tried adding border-bottom: none; in this area below, and it didn't work.

```
a,
button,
input:focus,
input[type="button"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"],
textarea:focus,
.button,
.gallery img,
.wp-custom-logo .site-title > a,
.wp-custom-logo .title-area,
.site-header {
    transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, color 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

My site is https://www.maximizingmoney.com/, and I basically want to remove the green line that appears below the logo, which turns reddish when you hover over the logo.

I was able to remove any errant lines from anywhere else using the border-bottom: none; attribute, but I can't get it to work for the line under the logo.

This is my first time here, so sorry if I am messing up or not following protocol.

Thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Site Logo is surrounded by a class named "custom-logo-link". So try to add

```
.custom-logo-link {
    border:0,
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. By using the class named "custom-logo-link" I was able to resolve the issue, so I really appreciate your help. I couldn't have figured that out without you. I'll post the entire code I used separately, in case anyone else has a similar issue, but your help is what resolved the issue, so I gave you the green check. Thank you again very much.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of the answer from Andre, I was able to resolve this issue.

Here is the full code that I used for future reference if anybody else has a similar issue.

```
.custom-logo-link,
.custom-logo-link:focus,
.custom-logo-link:hover {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Basically, using "border:0;" that Andre suggested did work (make sure to use ; instead of , I believe), but I used the "border-bottom: none;" attribute, and that worked as well.

Then, I just had to add the separate code for focus/hover to remove the line from appearing when hovering over the logo.

So the issue is resolved now. Thank you very much.